# Регулярное выражение - слово из букв и цифр

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

В строке

```
"Теоретики3 и 2п4423рактики палинд4442рома выделили
2многочис2ленные4 погран24ичные2 с пал24инд4ром4м формы"
```

найти слова состоящие из цифр и букв.

Не могу написать регулярное выражение для задания, получилось только это:

```
([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+\d+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+)|(\d+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+)|([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+\d+)
```

Но тогда слово `пал24инд4ром4м` разбивается на три, а `погран24ичные2` не полностью выделяется.

Comment: Очевидно, что необходимо делать привязку к краю слова
\b...\b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
((([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+\d+)|(\d+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+))[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ\d]*)
```

т.е. ((одна или более буква, затем одна или более цифра) или (одна или более цифра, затем одна или более буква)) потом буквы либо цифры

Comment: Как-то слишком переборно...

Answer (score 3):

Регулярка такая (надо выставить флаг игнорирования регистра):

```
(?=\w*(?!\d)\w)(?=\w*\d)\w+
```

Без подчёркиваний так:

```
\b(?=\w*(?!\d)\w)(?=\w*\d)(?=((?!_)\w)+\b)\w+
```

Кстати, никакой привязки к языкам :)

http://ideone.com/ZdG7Sa
http://ideone.com/sIsUF4

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "Теоретики3 и 2п4423ра_ктики палинд4442рома выделили\n" +
                  "2многочис2ленные4 погран24ичные2 с пал24и_нд4ром4м формы";

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str, @"(?=\w*(?!\d)\w)(?=\w*\d)\w+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);

        Console.WriteLine("===");

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str, @"\b(?=\w*(?!\d)\w)(?=\w*\d)(?=((?!_)\w)+\b)\w+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не подойдёт, так как нужно слово из букв и цифр, а в \w ещё входит символ '_'.

Comment: @BabaYaga, в чём проблема его исключить? И вообще, чем он не угодил в качестве буквы?

Comment: В каком алфавите вы видели знак нижнего подчёркивания?

Comment: @BabaYaga, в любом :) `(?=((?!_)\w)+)\b`

Comment: @BabaYaga, ответ дополнен.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите выбрать все кроме цифр:

```
\b(?=[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9]*[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9]+\b
```